# Change date in a linux system but after reboot the new date is lost

Tags: c, linux, date, reboot

I am programming an embedded system that takes the current date and time of an NMEA message. If the system date and time differ by more than 5 minutes from the NMEA message, I set the new date and time in the system and then I reboot it. The problem is that after reboot the system, it starts with the old date and time. The code is:

```
if (difference > 5){
    time_t t = mktime(&tmdate);
    timeval systemdate;
    systemdate.tv_sec = t;
    systemdate.tv_usec = 0;
    settimeofday(&systemdate,0);
    sync();
    reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT);
}
```

Comment: Do you have ntpd installed? It may automatically sync your system time. What distro are you running?

Comment: NTP restored your time from Internet.

Comment: That's not really a programming question - it's more a [unix.se] question (*"How do I ensure that my real-time clock is correct at next boot?"*).  Hint - look at at `hwclock --systohc`, assuming you have a working battery-backed RTC.

Comment: I am not using internet, my embedded system is working as a BTS through OpenBTS software. For that reason it is so important to have the correct time. @TobySpeight

Answer (score 1):

Your code change system time, but not hardwaretime. "man rtc" for details. You need something like this:

```
    struct rtc_time {
       int tm_sec;
       int tm_min;
       int tm_hour;
       int tm_mday;
       int tm_mon;
       int tm_year;
    };

    struct rtc_time rt;
    /* set values from NMEA to rt */
    fd = open("/dev/rtc", O_RDONLY);
    ioctl(fd, RTC_SET_TIME, &rt);
    close(fd);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you said to me but it still working with the same problem. I do not know what's wrong...